# Java nio move folder with content throws exception

Tags: java, file-io, nio

How can I move a folder to another. Like the ctrl + x function in windows.

So i want to copy myfoldertocopy which contains files and folders to another destination:

> C:\Users\myfoldertocopy
>   To
>   D:\data\

So i tried it with

```
public static void moveFolder(File source, File target){
    try {
        Files.move(source.toPath(), target.toPath().resolve(source.toPath().getFileName()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

but i throws an DirectoryNotEmptyException. 
So how i can move the complete myfoldertocopy with ALL content to another location?
Need i to iterate over it, or am i just using the move-method wrong?

Comment: How about `source.renameTo(target);`